# QProcess not reading result from command

Tags: qt, qprocess

I am trying to run some llvm commands in Qt with QProcess:

```
    QProcess* compile = new QProcess();
    compile->setWorkingDirectory("/Users/xxx/Documents/");

    compile->start("clang-check test.cpp -ast-dump -ast-dump-filter=main --"); 
//  compile->start("clang -Xclang -ast-dump test.cpp");

    compile->waitForFinished(-1);

    qDebug() << compile->readAll() << endl;
    qDebug() << compile->readAllStandardOutput() << endl;
    qDebug() << compile->readAllStandardError() << endl;
```

While the first start command with `clang-check` does not output any result but the second command with `clang` does output the expected result. I wonder what would cause such problem? And I have made sure that by directly entering the commands they both work.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems strange what you say, I do get a way out.

Answer (score 0):

I already faced this issue, try connecting the `QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput` and `QProcess::readyReadStandardError` than handle the output in the slots:

```
connect(&compile, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, [this]() {
    qDebug() << "Std output:" << compile->readAllStandardOutput();
});

connect(&compile, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, this, [this]() {
    qDebug() << "Err output:" << compile->readAllStandardError();
});
```

Also, check that the process starts correctly with the `QProcess::waitForStarted()`.

**Side note**: check the `new QProcess` that may lead to a memory leak.